# Trying to find if there are at least 2 words in a string

Tags: java

I am trying to find out if a phrase entered by the user has at least 2 words in it. If it does not, keep asking them to enter a phrase until they enter one with at least 2 words.

Here is my code so far: It can successfully detect if they have entered 2 words, and it successfully detects if they don't enter 2 words the FIRST time, but if they enter below 2 words again the second time the program quit.

```
private static void stringfunctions() {
    String phrase;
    int count = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (count < 2) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a multiple word phrase: ");
        phrase = input.nextLine();
        String[] arrPhrase = phrase.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrPhrase.length; i++) {
            if (arrPhrase[i].equals(" ")) {
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Should this be tagged as homework?

Comment: Sounds like homework, so here's a hint: make the logic to find out if there's at least two words in the input into a separate method. It'll make it easier to use it. Also, keep in mind that this might give false positives for multiple spaces in sequence, as well as ignoring stuff like tab characters. You might want to look into regular expressions, play around with them and see if you can come up with a regexp that detects your criterium.

Comment: You're going to want to look up regex, to be able to split on more than one whitespace character.  At that point, you shouldn't need to do a count, you should just be able to detect the number of words from the size of the array (you should use a boolean variable to control the loop - `inputTwoWords` or something).  Also - try thinking about why users only have to input 1 word in the second time they input something, if that's causing the program to quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to give you the answer, but watch closely the value of count as you travel through the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't expecting a direct answer

Answer (score 3):

reset count after testing.  the problem is the while loop terminates as soon as count passes 2